# Getting bumps for an account that may be an ATA or not

Tags: anchor, bump, ata

Let's say I have a token account and I want to check if the owner is the signer OR the account is an ATA and the signer is one of the seeds.

```
    pub some_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
```

So I set up something like:

```
    let bump = ctx.bumps.get("some_account").unwrap_or(&255);
    let some_acc_owner: Pubkey = some_account.owner;
    if !some_acc_owner.eq(&payer.key()) && !some_acc_owner.eq(ata_authority) {
        // error
    }

    if some_acc_owner.eq(ata_authority) {
        let derive = anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey::create_program_address(
            &[
                b"whatever".as_ref(),
                payer.key().as_ref(),
                &[*bump],
            ],
            program_id,
        );
        match derive {
            Ok(key) => {
                if !key.eq(&some_account.key()) {
                    // err
                }
            }
            Err(_) => {
                // err
            }
        };
    }
```

But here Anchor is *not* getting the bump in those scenarios where the account is an ATA. Besides passing the bump in arguments, how can I retrieve the bump for a maybe-but-maybe-not derived account?

Comment: For reference, if you only need to validate the canonical bump (e.g., you used init to create the ATA), you can use `find_program_address` and compare that instead, but you if you want to support all bumps, not just the canonical one, the question stands.

Comment: ATAs only ever use the canonical bump based on its own program logic, and they're never exposed or passed in from the outside. Here you're trying to derive an address with your own program id, which means that is is *not* an ATA. Maybe you can rephrase your question with some background about what you're trying to do?

Comment: There's a couple elements to the question: (1) `find_program_address` uses more compute than create, so it would be preferable to use create, (2) Is it possible to have the bump tree save the bump for `some_acc` only in cases where it is an ATA? Agree that the canonical bump is generally fine, but would nice to get the canonical bump from ctx.bumps when the acc is an ATA.

Comment: For #2, Anchor could save the bump seed somewhere during the `AssociatedToken` constraint generation at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/5e13431aca29cecd4bd2179c12b593dc4aa0fec5/lang/syn/src/codegen/accounts/constraints.rs#L595. Keep in mind that the seed is only used once during ATA creation in the ATA program, and nowhere else. So maybe we need to get to the core of your question. What do you want to do with the ATA bump seed?

Comment: In the above example, you have a key that might be an ATA, or might not. If it is an ATA, it was made earlier, in another ix. You can't use a simple seeds constraint check because the key might not be an ATA. We need the bump to check if the ATA is valid with `create_program_address`, or we can use `find_program_address`, which will regenerate that canonical bump, but costs more compute.